# Generating an extended compiler in ASIPmeister

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am using ASIPmeister tool to customize a base processor by adding new instructions to the processor. And then tool itself generates corresponding compiler if new instruction's C definition are added in the tool. I have added a AVERAGE, SWAP, MINMAX and BRANCH_IF_GREAT_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO C definitions, as in the attached picture.
The tool manual says that all new instructions should have C definitions as in the attached picture and then later can be accessed using keyword __builtin_browni32_XXX. It also says that all instruction that returns 0 or more than 1 operands it should return a void type and more than 1 values are returned by reference. Now, my AVG, SWAP and XNOR which return one value are added in the compiler and I can access them properly as in the below code (commented lines), but I am having problem in using BGUE and MINMAX instruction in C code. I tried the following:

```
unsigned int array[10] = { 45, 75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int main() {
  //array[2] = __builtin_brownie32_NXOR(array[0], array[1]);
  //array[3] = __builtin_brownie32_AVG(array[0], array[1]);
  //array[4] = __builtin_brownie32_SWAP(array[0]);
  __builtin_brownie32_MINMAX(&array[5],&array[6], array[0], array[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following assembly code:

```
    .globl  _array
.data
    .align 2
    .type   _array, @object
    .size   _array, 40
_array:
    .long   45
    .long   75
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .zero   4
.text
    .align 2
    .globl  _main
    .type   _main, @function
_main:
;  Function 'main'; 0 bytes of locals, 0 regs to save, 0 byte of out. args. size.
    sw  -4(r5),r3   ; push LinkRegister(r3)
    sw  -8(r5),r4   ; push FrameRegister(r4)
    addi    r4, r5,#-8  ; FramePtr = StackPtr-8
    addi    r5,r5,#-8   ; alloc local storage
    addi    r6,r0,%hi(_array+20)
    lsoi    r6,r6,%lo(_array+20)
    add r8,r0,r6
    addi    r6,r0,%hi(_array+24)
    lsoi    r6,r6,%lo(_array+24)
    add r9,r0,r6
    addi    r6,r0,%hi(_array)
    lsoi    r6,r6,%lo(_array)
    lw  r6,(r6)
    nop
    add r7,r0,r6
    addi    r6,r0,%hi(_array)
    lsoi    r6,r6,%lo(_array)
    lw  r6,4(r6)
    nop
    MINMAX r8 , r9 , r7 , r6 
    addi    r6,r0,#0
    lw  r3,4(r4)    ; pop LinkRegister(r3)
    addi    r5,r4,#8    ; StackPointer = FramePointer+8
    lw  r4,(r4)     ; restore FramePointer
    jpr r3      ; return
    .size   _main, .-_main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.2"
```

This assembly code indicates that MINMAX uses r8 and r9 as the returned values but in the assembly code they are not further used any  where to be saved into array.
Is there any mistake in the usage? Is there any alternative or suggestions.
Regards

Tool Manual's Relevant Page:
[image: Tool Manual's Relevant Page]
C Definition added in the tool:

[image: C Definition added in the tool]
Instructions:

[image: Instructions]

Comment: You have a mismatch between the instruction and what the compiler expects. The builtin accepts pointers to the return values hence the compiler expects it to write the result there automatically. Your instruction however only writes to the registers not to the memory addressed by them. I am not familiar with your tools, so I can't help in fixing it.

Comment: As in the attached picture above, they gives example of a DIV instruction and I used same syntax. Please have a look.

Comment: Yeah I see that but that doesn't show the table in the tool. Maybe `DIV` takes something else than `GPR`?

Comment: If it would have been different that GPR, it would have not been used as rd1 and rd2 in the tutorial.

Comment: The same MINMAX works fine when inserted using __asm__ directive.

  __asm__ volatile (
                "minmax %[my_out1], %[my_out2], %[my_op1], %[my_op2]\n\t"
                : [my_out1] "=&r" (array[5]), [my_out2] "=&r" (array[4])
                : [my_op1] "r" (array[0]), [my_op2] "r" (array[1])
        );

@Jester

Comment: That's expected since that does not pass an address. Somewhere in the builtin implementation there should be code that translates from the address form to the register one but I have no idea how that works.